# Jumpdrive-Portable Database with GUI frontend

Tags: database, open-source, tags

Is there a simple database program to let me collect, sort, tag, and reguritate trivia questions and answers?

If something already exists in Open Source, can you point me to that?  I have assembly programming skills (cue jokes) but not so much in the Perl,LINQ,Delphi,VB, C#, Java arena.

Comment: Database-enabled apps that need to be portable have generally evolved toward the web, not toward, say, flash drives.  For the longest time, flash drives weren't a cost-effective way to move databases around.  Instead, you might think about a web application instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task will not be very difficult.  It would be a good way to learn C# (which I most recommend for this because of the ease of creating GUIs with it).  You could just store the data in a text file or a serialized dictionary.

If your database is going to get big, you might consider using SQLite instead (which stores the database as a regular file).  I don't know the state of C# bindings for SQLite, but there probably are some.

Good luck!